# AWS Lambda Error: Unable to import module 'function_name': No module named 'module._module'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, impala, impyla

#### Please see the screenshots in particular after reading.

I am deploying a python script on AWS Lambda which uses the package `impyla` which has a dependency on the package `bitarray`.

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
```

My python file is called `authorize_ingress.py` which has a function called `handle_authorize_ingress(event, context)` which are properly configured. See the screenshots below:

My function's file:

[image: function]

The handler in lambda specified:

[image: handler]

The handler in code itself:

[image: handler]

and my zip file has everything in the root (and not nested within a directory):

[image: file]

The package `bitarray` is installed automatically by `impyla`:

[image: bitarray]

Every single time, I am met with this response:

### [image: response]

As of now, I have tried to:

- The package was generated with `zip -r` option.
- The files are in the root of the zip and not nested within a directory.
- The function works perfectly fine locally.
- I have tried both `virtualenv` and simply installing the dependencies in a `packages/` path but no luck

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? I generated my deployment package following [AWS' Lambda Deployment Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html). Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Looks like you didn't pack `bitarray` into the deployment package.

Comment: @jellycsc that's the thing, it is there. I am running the exact same package in the `venv` locally and it runs fine. When the exact same package is deployed, it cannot seem to find it.

Comment: If you tell me the exact python dependencies, I can bake a layer zip for you.

Comment: @jellycsc  I depend on only two main dependencies.

(1) impyla: https://pypi.org/project/impyla/
(2) boto3: https://pypi.org/project/boto3/

`bitarray` is a dependency of `impyla` and is installed along with it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. You can download this lambda layer through this gdrive [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17KU9-wWoVl5Bm84znpPDZD20yifgYvOS/view?usp=sharing). This layer is compatible with Python 3.8, so make sure you select the correct lambda runtime.

If you are curious to know how I generated this lambda layer, here is a list of basically what I did:

- Serverless Framework
- serverless-python-requirements plugin
- docker
- serverless.yml

```
service: serverless-example

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  region: us-east-1
  profile: dummy

functions:
  dummy:
    handler: dummy.handler

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    layer: true
```

- requirements.txt

```
impyla==0.16.2
```

Then simply do `sls package -p pkg`. The layer named `pythonRequirements.zip` will be ready in a minute under `.serverless` directory.

Comment: I don't know why some people get upset about my answer :D, let me know the reason please.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer but saw this comment and believe the reason is that typically people don't want to have to rely on another framework (serverless) to solve a problem like this. Honestly, it's a pretty big ask if someone has a concern and the answer is to learn a new framework... a better answer would be to explain what is wrong and how it could be solved using existing constraints, then you could certainly link to serverless and say it may be easier if you are familiar with framework x, etc.