# Installing matplotlib from wheel for aws lambda

Tags: matplotlib, aws-lambda, python-wheel

I want to use matplotlib to create image files in an AWS Lambda function. Since my system does not run the same version of Linux that Lambda uses, I received the guidance to download a wheel (.whl file) from the matplotlib website. I downloaded matplotlib-3.3.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d2/43/2bd63467490036697e7be71444fafc7b236923d614d4521979a200c6b559/matplotlib-3.3.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

to the folder where I am creating my deployment package.

> > > First of all, I there are many wheel files and it is not clear if this is the correct one to use. Second, it doesn't work.

THen I upacked the wheel with the command

```
wheel unpack *.whl
```

This produced a directory with the matplotlib package in it.

My main function is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot

def lambda_handler(event, context):
return
```

I gave the commands

```
zip -r my-deployment-package.zip .
zip -g my-deployment-package.zip lambda_function.py
```

and uploaded the zip to an s3 bucket. Then I used the "aws lambda update-function-code..." command to update the lambda function. When I deploy and test, I get the error: "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'matplotlib'"

Thinking that the matplotlib module is not there (perhaps I need to do something with the whl file or put it in a different place), i activated my virtual environment and started the python interpreter. Trying to import matplotlib, I get "module not found." Trying to use pip install on the matplotlib directory, it complains that there is no setup.py:

```
$ pip install --no-index --find-links=. matplotlib-3.3.3/
ERROR: Directory 'matplotlib-3.3.3/' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
```

How can I get the module to be recognized?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Serverless framework and Docker, you can build a layer in a minute. Check out my answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62945616/10692493).

If you are in a hurry, feel free to grab this lambda layer that I packaged for you. It's compatible with Python 3.8. Here is the gdrive download [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11c44FWG6ATx5BVO_CXv_tnDMe8wp20UR/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Read your post, didn;t understand it much. Don;t know anything about Lambda layers. Is Serverless an AWS thing, an application of Docker or what? I will Google. My attempts with matplotlib were intended as a proof of concept, There will be other dependencies, for example Pandas

Comment: I see that Lamda has a size limit of 250 MB, unzipped. For matplotlib, that is 180 MB. Since I need Pandas too, I think this quota limit kills my idea

Comment: An alternative is to put your library into EFS, and let lambda import packages from there.

Answer (score 0):

No need to build your own layer; loads of those available at https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers - you just have to include them in your Lambda config.